# Rasbian Lite: email Python Package install (No module named 'cStringIO')

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, debian, package-managers

Sorry for possible duplicate. I am using Rasbian Lite OS. When I try to install package email:

```
 pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo pip3 install email
```

I get error message:

```
 Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
 Collecting email
 Using cached email-4.0.2.tar.gz (1.2 MB)
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-298bk50t/email/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-298bk50t/email/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-298bk50t/email/pip-egg-info
     cwd: /tmp/pip-install-298bk50t/email/
Complete output (11 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    import setuptools.version
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/setuptools/version.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "/tmp/pip-install-298bk50t/email/email/parser.py", line 10, in <module>
    from cStringIO import StringIO
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cStringIO'
----------------------------------------
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

However, when I run:

```
 sudo pip install cStringIO
```

I get an error:

```
 Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cStringIO (from versions: none)
 ERROR: No matching distribution found for cStringIO
```

So it seems I am stuck because I can't install cStringIO?
Any ideas/suggestions/solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: cstringio was a Python 2 standard library that doesn't exist any more in 3. I'm guessing that library you're trying to install was abandoned before the 2->3 transition

Answer (score 0):

Solved: was using wrong python version inside terminal